# How to pass a ***char from C to Go

Tags: go, cgo

I have a C API function that returns a `uint32_t` as the size of an array and returns a `***char`. Note that the C API function is from a third party library. Specifically the C API function implementation is from [MXNET](https://github.com/apache/mxnet/blob/b84609d3fc73d20929c114eab95faaa56e6c5ede/src/c_api/c_api_symbolic.cc#L81C5-L81C21), and here is the [CAPI header definition](https://github.com/apache/mxnet/blob/b84609d3fc73d20929c114eab95faaa56e6c5ede/include/mxnet/c_api.h#L1437C15-L1437C31)

I am wanting to understand the the steps of using unsafe.slice to convert the `***char` to a string slice  `[]string`

C API Example:

```
  void MyCAPIFunction(uint32_t *out_size, const char ***out_array);
```

I tried the following as a naive attempt

```
func GetStringSlice() (names []string) {

    size_ptr := C.malloc(8)
    defer C.free(size_ptr)

    names_ptr := C.malloc(8)
    defer C.free(names_ptr)

    C.MyCAPIFunction((*C.uint32_t)(size_ptr), (***C.char)(names_ptr))

    names = unsafe.Slice((*string)(names_ptr), *(*uint32)(size_ptr))
    return
}
```

And get the following error

```
panic: runtime error: growslice: len out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
fmt.(*buffer).writeString(...)
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/print.go:108
fmt.(*fmt).padString(0x19?, {0x2da7, 0xe066a4ed220cd213})
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/format.go:110 +0x217
fmt.(*fmt).fmtS(0x200000003?, {0x2da7?, 0xc0000b94d8?})
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/format.go:359 +0x39
fmt.(*pp).fmtString(0x22c1ee?, {0x2da7?, 0xc0000b9688?}, 0x486d2e?)
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/print.go:494 +0x85
fmt.(*pp).printArg(0xc00009e4e0, {0x49ae00?, 0xc000016210}, 0x76)
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/print.go:741 +0x1bb
fmt.(*pp).doPrintln(0xc00009e4e0, {0xc0000b99f0?, 0x1, 0x0?})
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/print.go:1223 +0x38
fmt.Appendln({0xc0000c0200, 0x14, 0x200}, {0xc0000b99f0, 0x1, 0x1})
        /snap/go/10389/src/fmt/print.go:332 +0x54
main.main.Println.func39({0xc0000c0200?, 0xc000012018?, 0x407dfd?})
        /snap/go/10389/src/log/log.go:406 +0x25
log.(*Logger).output(0xc00009c090, 0x0, 0x8?, 0xc0000b9e00)
        /snap/go/10389/src/log/log.go:238 +0x37b
log.Println(...)
        /snap/go/10389/src/log/log.go:405
main.main()
        /home/tjad/capi/cmd/main.go:135 +0x2286
exit status 2
```

I understand there must be a mismatch in the conversion of types, but am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Go `string` types are not just aliases for raw memory. They have Go's GC runtime management looking after them.

Can you change your approach to convert the memory data into regular Go `string`s. Do something like this:

```golang
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte("one\000two\000three")
    var names []string
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        p := unsafe.Pointer(&b[i])
        s := C.GoString((*C.char)(p))
        i += len(s)
        names = append(names, s)
    }
    fmt.Println(b, names)
}
```

In your case, if the returned array is actually an array of pointers, you will need something more elaborate:

```golang
package main

// #include <stdint.h>
import "C"

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "unsafe"
)

func appendPtr(buf *bytes.Buffer, p unsafe.Pointer) {
    var err error
    up := uintptr(p)
    switch unsafe.Sizeof(p) {
    case 4:
        err = binary.Write(buf, binary.NativeEndian, uint32(up))
    case 8:
        err = binary.Write(buf, binary.NativeEndian, uint64(up))
    default:
        log.Fatalf("not expecting value of size %d", unsafe.Sizeof(p))
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to write pointer: %v", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    var size C.uint32_t
    var names_ptr **C.char

    // Use some Go to fake the return values of a C-API call.
    b := []byte("one\000two\000three\000")
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        appendPtr(buf, unsafe.Pointer(&b[i]))
        i += bytes.IndexByte(b[i:], 0)
    }
    size = C.uint32_t(buf.Len())
    names_ptr = (**C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf.Bytes()[0]))

    // Given these values, unpack them into something Go can
    // handle natively. This first line creates a large Go byte
    // array alias for the "C" memory block. Note, 1<<30 is
    // intended to be plenty large enough, but the size value is
    // the important part, which cuts the potential range down to
    // what is actually available from the C-API result.
    var p *C.char
    mem := (*[1 << 30]*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(names_ptr))[:uintptr(size)/unsafe.Sizeof(p)]

    var names []string
    for i:=0; i<len(mem);i++ {
        s := C.GoString(mem[i])
        names = append(names, s)
    }

    fmt.Println(b, names)
}
```

Comment: I'm writing bindings for a third party library, I can't change the return types of the CAPI.

Comment: @TjadClark I've extended my answer with an example of unpacking an array of char pointers.

Comment: Further simplified with more aggressive type aliasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your updates Tinkerer! I am going to attempt using this during tomorrow. Really appreciate your input for this.